# How do I edit Vertex Properties in OrientDB?

Tags: java, orientdb

I have a vertex that I pulled using the following `g.getVertexByKey("object", "Foo")`. The `object` key is indexed, but it has other properties like `count`. It looks somewhat like this:

```
Vertex V:
- object (idx)
- count
```

How do I update the **count** property for the vertex?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Vertex instance you can use

`v.setProperty(final String key, final Object value);`

then v.save()